# Conditionally change CSS with AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to change the background-color of a div based on the value of an Angular expression. I have the following div:

```
<div class="outer">
  <h4 class="weather-heading">It's currently {{weather}}</h4>
</div>
```

Based on the value of {{weather}} (i.e. sunny, cloudy), I want to change the background-color of the outer div. What's the best way to do this with angular?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass)?

Comment: the best way is to put the view' logic in directive

Comment: @Cherniv can you give a code example?

Comment: you can start from ngClass as incutonez suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @incutonez said, you could use `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-class="{'sunny': weather == 'Sunny', 'rainy': weather == 'Rainy'}">
  <h4 class="weather-heading">It's currently {{weather}}</h4>
</div>
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sDwWJVbkFv6fMiBt7NbU?p=preview).

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it may be more appropriate to create a directive, as @Cherniv has suggested.